# Many to Many between IdentityUser and other table in a separate context

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am having difficulty creating a join table relationship between my Identity Framework `IdentityContext`(the `IdentityUser`) and one of my other tables Let's call it `Entry`. The problem is, `Entry` is in an entirely separate context doing it's own thing as well.

What is the proper way to associate these two? Where do I define the Join Table in fluent api?

Right now, I am getting the following error.

```
The key {'ApplicationUserId'} contains properties in shadow state and is referenced by a relationship from 'ApplicationUser.ApplicationUserEntries' to 'ApplicationUserEntry.ApplicationUser'. Configure a non-shadow principal key for this relationship.
```

These are how my tables are defined.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        ...

        public virtual List<ApplicationUserEntry> ApplicationUserEntries { get; set; }
    }


public class Entry
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        ...

        public virtual List<ApplicationUserEntry> ApplicationUserEntries { get; set; }
    }
```

And the join table as follows.

```
public class ApplicationUserEntry
    {
        public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public int EntryId { get; set; }
        public Entry Entry { get; set; }
    }
```

For the `IdentityContext` I have just some generic setup for other properties

```
var users = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>();
        users.Property(u => u.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(65);
        users.Property(u => u.FirstName).HasMaxLength(32);
        users.Property(u => u.LastName).HasMaxLength(32);
```

And in my GoalsContext I have some general setup for other unrelated stuff, and the join table defined for `ApplicationUserEntry`

```
// Entry Configuration
var entries = modelBuilder.Entity<Entry>();
            entries.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            entries.HasAlternateKey(e => new { e.MilestoneId, e.CategoryId, e.MetricId });
            entries.Property(e => e.Value).IsRequired();
            entries.Property(e => e.Locked).IsRequired().HasDefaultValue(false);
            entries.ToTable("GoalsEntries");

// ApplicationUserEntry Join Table
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserEntry>()
            .ToTable("GoalsApplicationUserEntry")
            .HasKey(se => new { se.ApplicationUserId, se.EntryId });

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserEntry>()
            .HasOne(se => se.ApplicationUser)
            .WithMany(s => s.ApplicationUserEntries)
            .HasForeignKey(se => se.ApplicationUserId);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserEntry>()
            .HasOne(se => se.Entry)
            .WithMany(e => e.ApplicationUserEntries)
            .HasForeignKey(se => se.EntryId);
```

Now I'm sure I'm obviously missing something but I can't figure out what. I've never attempted to create a many to many relationship between two tables that are defined in two different contexts... and not even sure if that's wise or not to do.

My ultimate goal is to be able to associate owners with `Entry` records, so they can only be modified by the owners, which I verify with Identity Framework.

Ideally I would just prefer a unidirectional relationship, so I can find the owner from the `Entry`, but I'm not intending to get a list of `Entry` by looking at the `IdentityUser`

Comment: My `Entry` context is a whole separate beast, and I merely wish to create a seam, to track ownership utilizing identity. If possible to avoid merging everything into a single context, I would prefer that.

Comment: Is my best course of action really to just use a single DbContext for my site on anything that would need access to a user's information?

Comment: There are a ton of posts on this topic. Having your app context inherit from the identitycontext is simplest. The workarounds do something like storing the user key without a relationship and then doing a separate lookup.